# Relation between Uniform convergence and absolute convergence of power series in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Does uniform convergence of a power series always imply absolute convergence in $\mathbb{C}$? Can anyone help me to prove or disprove the statement?

In general are there any relation between this two?

Comment: Are you considering power series or general function series?

Comment: Power series...

Comment: On $[-1,0]$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1nx^n$ converges uniformly, but not absolutely

Comment: Also, on $(0,1)$ the series $\sum x^n$ is absolutely convergent but not uniformly

Comment: In case of complex numbers, is the scenario same? I updated my question..

Comment: @roydiptajit The complex variable does not invalidate the counterexamples.

Comment: Sorry yes, so aren't there any relation between this two notions of convergence?

Comment: The relation is that on the interior of the disc of convergence, power series converge absolutely. On compact subsets of the interior, they also converge uniformly. So on compact subsets of the interior, they converge both absolutely and uniformly.

Comment: For a series of functions, Wikipedia has the wonderful statement *"A series can be uniformly convergent and absolutely convergent without being [uniformly absolutely-convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_absolute-convergence)."*